# Почему-то не работают функции cos(x) и sin(x)?

Tags: c++

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    double x, y, d;
    int xx, yy;
    d = d + 0.06;

    x = 400 + 100*cos(d); // строка не работает, почему?
    y = 400 + 100*sin(d);

    Canvas->MoveTo(100, 100);
    Canvas->LineTo(x, y);
}
```

Многоуважаемые программисты, объясните, пожалуйста, студенту, в чем он не прав? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хоть ответы принимаем, или как???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это, я так понимаю, C++ Builder? А хедер cmath не должен быть вставлен?

Еще обращает внимание:

```
double d;
d = d + 0.06;
```

Вы производите действия с неинициализированной переменной. Это не очень хорошо.

Comment: Да это C++ Builder 6, хедер вроде стоит! Не понимаю, что значит неинициализированная переменная?

Comment: Когда вы пишите что-то типа

double d;

компилятор отводит место в памяти под эту переменную. Локальные переменные располагаются в такой штуке как стек. Пока вы не присвоили этой переменной какое-то определенное значение (d = 4.4 или через операцию с другой определенной переменной или константой) в этой ячейке находится то, что было в ней раньше. А это может быть все, что угодно, поскольку стек используют все функции и после этого он не очищается, просто изменяется значение регистра, указывающего на вершину стека.

Comment: оо как все сложно, теперь понятно спасибо вам))

Comment: Ничего сложного на самом деле нет. Рекомендую немного почитать про ассемблер, тогда все сразу ясно станет.

Comment: спасибо за рекомендации обязательно почитаю

Comment: Спасибо  - это хорошо. А плюсик наверху поставили?

Comment: Недостаточно очков уважения

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "sin(3.14) = " << sin(3.14) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод.

> `sin(3.14) = 0.00159265`

Итого.

1. Подключить заголовок.
2. Убедиться в правильности вызова.

Comment: Ооо... заработала, спасибо вам большое. Всегда программировал в делфи, а тут решил C++ попробовать, понятия не имел, что придется подключать заголовки. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<cmath>//теперь должно работать
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    double x=0, y=0, d=0;/*тут была ошибка-переменные заполнены "мусором"-тем, что было в памяти на тот момент*/
    int xx, yy;
    d = d + 0.06;

    x = 400 + 100*cos(d); // строка не работает, почему?
    y = 400 + 100*sin(d);/*потому что вы не подключили cmath, который хранит описание
sin(), cos(), M_PI и т.д*/

    Canvas->MoveTo(100, 100);
    Canvas->LineTo(x, y);
}
```